# Вместе с ответом от ajax приходит сторонний код

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Суть такова: есть ajax функция, которая отправляет 5 различных заголовков (соответственно заголовки: "st","so","ga","vi","mo"), в зависимости от действий пользователя, на сервер и получает ответ ввиде объекта.
[image: возвращается объект]
При отправки 4ёх из 5ти заголовков, всё работает верно и возвращается объект, но при отправке пятого ("ga"), мне возвращается объект и сторонний код ввиде рекламного блока ВМЕСТЕ с этим объектом.
[image: объект И сторонний код]
Я точно уверен, что в базе у меня нет такого кода, который приходит мне ответом с сервера, а значит и сервер не мог его туда поместить. Код как-то приплетается сам.
Как это ликвидировать или как мне отделить объект от этого инородного кода в js?

Comment: Не заставляйте нас ломать глаза с вашими скриншотами, приведите кусок программы и ответы сервера в вопросе в текстовом виде.

Comment: @sercxjo в ответе приходит огромный объект, с закодированной кириллицей, я не думаю, что на это интересно смотреть. Код тоже огромный, и вот зуб даю, там нет этого рекламного блока. Этот блок как-то сторонним способом приплетается, возможно причина в хостинге, так как на локальном сервере у меня всё правильно работает.

Comment: @Diskyp ну если вы не хотите ничего показывать, то какой помощи вы ожидаете? Экстрасенсы находятся на канале ТНТ. .... А в целом по предоставленной информации можно также сказать: у вас что-то не то, зуб даю.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский хорошо, для особо остроумных объясню коротко и понятно: ПРОБЛЕМА НЕ В КОДЕ. Если тебе так хочется посмотреть на мой шикарный php код, то напиши почту, я тебе персонально скину.

Comment: @Diskyp если вы не знаете, что это за ресурс и каковы его правила - то, думаю, стоит вам с ними ознакомиться в разделе [Справка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) . А в хрустальный шар играть никто не будет

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский ты издеваешься? У меня проблема не с программным кодом, дак зачем мне писать его? Он прекрасно работает на локальном сервере, но мой хостинг как-то приплетает свой код к моему ajax. Вопрос стоит не найти причину, а как избавиться от проблемы (как-то отсеять этот код от объекта в js, к примеру). Вот что тут непонятного? Зачем мне забивать свой вопрос тонной бесполезной информации?

Comment: @Diskyp попробуйте проверить крайнюю точку на сервере непосредственно перед отправкой ответа клиенту, если там все в порядке тогда нужно будет думать, если там есть лишние данные то проблема где-то в коде. Еще как вариант проблему может вызывать расширение в браузере.

Comment: @Diskyp, что за хостинг используете? Не бесплатный случайно?

Comment: @Kison да, бесплатный, и он добавлял мне рекламный блок в конец страницы, но я скрыл его средствами js, но как это может отразиться на ajax я не понимаю. Сервер возвращает всё как надо, нужный мне объект, но почему-то именно заголовок "ga" вызывает добавление к ajax этого блока. На локальном сервере у меня такой проблемы нет.

Comment: @Diskyp, ссылку на сайт можете показать?

Comment: @Kison pryout.ru

Comment: @Diskyp есть возможность заменить `ga` на что-то другое?

Comment: @Diskyp, почему бы вам не поинтересоваться этим вопросом у самого хостера? Если проблема не в коде, то она в переферии сервера, к которой ни у нас, ни у Вас как я понимаю доступа нет. Ну на крайний случай перед ответом сделайте логи на стороне сервера и проверьте их.

Comment: @Diskyp, c чего вы взяли что у вас эти заголовки отправляются?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский да, я как раз это сейчас и пробую, заменял ga на gl, а затем на sa и всёравно именно при отправке этого заголовка у меня возвращается ответ с рекламным блоком. Проверил код на сервере и там всё не тронуто, идентично с локальным.

Comment: @Kison В хроме есть headers, в которых написаны заголовки, и там он есть. К тому же я получаю нужный объект, но только с каким-то сторонним кодом.

Comment: @Alex Krass я попробую конечно, но шанс того, что у бесплатного хостинга есть тех. поддержка крайне мал. На мой взгляд проще как-то распарсить полученную строку.

Comment: @Diskyp если вопрос в том, как обработать ответ и убрать оттуда лишнее - покажите кусок js-кода, который этот ответ у вас принимает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче решил я свою проблему. Приходящий со сторонним кодом ответ естественно сбрасывался в error и там я сделал вот такой нехитрый парсинг:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
str=xhr.responseText.replace(/<div(\s|.)+<\/div>/,'');
str=JSON.parse(str);
},
```

Благодаря ему, из ответа удалялся инородный код, а строка преобразовывалась в объект. Это собственно то, в чём я и просил мне помочь.